# EF lens on an EF-S body

Tags: lens, canon

I have an EOS Rebel T7i and am wondering if I can put an EF 75mm-300mm lens on it.  Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: Yes, but be advised, speaking from experience, the EF 75-300 "kit" lens is rather bad. Check the 55-250STM (https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103274/canon-ef-75-300mm-f-4-5-6-iii-vs-ef-100-300mm-f-4-5-5-6-usm)

Comment: You'll be much better served by using the EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS STM (or even the older EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II) than the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 that is the worst lens in Canon's current lineup.

Comment: Yes, you can technically do it.  But it will become effectively a 120-480mm lens from an FOV perspective (no pun intended).  The 75-300 is not a great lens for detail in the first place, and putting it on a crop sensor body is kind of like putting a 1.4x tele behind it (except no 1 stop exposure loss).  So don't expect sharp results.  While many people have marked this as a duplicate, which for the most part it is, this question is about a specific lens and there are issues of quality beyond can you actually make it fit without damaging anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. EF lenses are compatible with EF-S bodies. I have a 7D Mark II (EF-S) and a few EF lenses, so I have direct experience with this - not just repeating something I've read somewhere.